# ¿Alguien que me diga porque me aparece este error al ejecutar en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy utilizando Python por primera vez, aquí quiero realizar lo siguiente: Escribir una función `cuadrados(l)` que recibiendo una secuencia `l` de números, devuelve la lista de los cuadrados de esos números, en el mismo orden.
Entonces hice lo siguiente:

```
def cuadrados1(l):
    a = [ a*a for a in l ]
    return a
```

Pero al ejecutar me marca el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No alcanzo a leer el error. ¿Qué dice? ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el texto mismo?

Comment: En la foto se ve un número 1 en vez de una letra l como argumento de tu función. Eso es sintaxis inválida. Tu pregunta terminará cerrada por ser un error tipográfico.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/21

Answer (score 2):

Según entiendo, deseas obtener el cuadrado de los números de una lista suponiendo que tu lista sea `sec` y contenga estos valores, puedes probar con lo siguiente:

```
sec = [2,4,5]

def cuadrados(lista):
  for i in lista:
      print (i*i)

cuadrados(sec)
```

Comment: La pregunta dice "devuelve la lista de los cuadrados", este código no devuelve la lista, solo imprime los valores. Tal y como ya tenía en su código, `lista = [a*a for a in l]` si que devuelve una lista de los cuadrados, lo único que cambiando el `1` por una letra/palabra, como ya le han dicho.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que no puedes utilizar números como parámetros cuando estás definiendo una función. Cambia el "1" por una letra o una palabra más significativa que le haga justicia al objeto que vas a ingresar cuando llames la función. Más info [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).